# commit com a anotação @Transactional no Spring

Tags: java, spring, transações, commit, annotation

Boa tarde! Sou novo em java e Spring e estou precisando de ajuda no código abaixo. Preciso que a cada iteração do for seja realizado o commit, porém só está sendo realizado no final da transação, cheguei a criar o método persiste achando que iria abrir uma nova transação e efetuar o commit, porém nada. Alguém poderia me informar como devo proceder? Desde já agradeço.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public String enviarPedidos() {
    LOGGER.info("MassivoPedido :: enviarPedidos");

    final String[] listStatus = {Constante.UPLOAD_MASS_STATUS_AG_ENVIO, Constante.ENVIAR_MASS_PED_ERROR};
    final List<MassivoPedido> massivoPedidos = this.buscarPorStatus(listStatus);
    final List<MassivoPedidoParametro> massivoPedidoParametros = this.massivoPedidoParametroComponent.findAll();
    final Date agora = new Date();
    JSONObject retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject;
    for (MassivoPedido massivoPedido : massivoPedidos) {
        try {
            for(MassivoPedidoParametro massivoPedidoParametro : massivoPedidoParametros){
                try {
                    if (massivoPedidoParametro.getCnpjFornecedor().equalsIgnoreCase(massivoPedido.getCnpjFornecedor())) {
                        retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject = Util.buildJSONObject((this.fornecedorClient.criarPedido(massivoPedidoParametro, massivoPedido).toString().replace("Status","returnCode").replace("Message","returnMessage")));
                        LOGGER.info("MassivoPedido :: enviarPedidos - {}", retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject.toString());

                        if (retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject.getString("returnCode").equals("1") || retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject.getString("returnCode").equals("ERROR")) {
                            massivoPedido.setDatahoraReg(agora);
                            massivoPedido.setRetornoFornecedor(retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject.toString());

                            massivoPedido.setStatus(Constante.ENVIAR_MASS_PED_ERROR);

                            if (retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject.getString("returnMessage").equals("Duplicate PoNo")) {
                                massivoPedido.setStatus(Constante.ENVIAR_MASS_PED_SUCCESS);
                            }

                        } else {
                            massivoPedido.setStatus(Constante.ENVIAR_MASS_PED_SUCCESS);
                            massivoPedido.setDatahoraReg(agora);
                            massivoPedido.setRetornoFornecedor(retornoCriarPedidoJSONObject.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    massivoPedido.setStatus(Constante.ENVIAR_MASS_PED_ERROR);
                    massivoPedido.setDatahoraReg(agora);
                    massivoPedido.setRetornoFornecedor("Erro ao criar pedido " + massivoPedido.getIdPedido() + " no fornecedor " + massivoPedido.getCnpjFornecedor() + " " + e.toString());
                }

                this.persiste(massivoPedido);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Erro ao enviarPedidos - Massivo Pedido. Erro: {}", e.toString());
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void persiste(MassivoPedido massivoPedido) {
    super.update(massivoPedido);
}
```

Comment: Envolve o código dentro do `for` em um método a parte com `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`. Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338150/how-to-manually-force-a-commit-in-a-transactional-method) deve resolver o seu problema. Se der certo me avisa que eu faço a resposta mesmo.

Comment: Tente criar outra classe, e dentro dela crie o método com essa propagação de transação que você usou no seu método. Esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821235/transactional-rollback-in-loop) tem uma lógica parecida com o que você precisa.

Comment: Oi @YgorAzevedo Tentei dessa forma e continuou dando o commit apenas no final da transação do primeiro método, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode extrair o comportamento que está dentro do for para um método e anotar esse novo método com o @Transaction, assim ele irá respeitar a transação tratada ali primeiro.

Comment: Danilo, seria interessante você postar um pouco de código para ilustrar o que você quer dizer.